# No such file or directory: dash

Tags: init-file, use-package, load-path

Since few days I am getting this error but I don't remember changing anything in my configuration. I have dash installed on my system. I was thinking then it needs dash Emacs package, but after installing it nothing has changed.

When I do evaluate the init.el buffer manually, my config runs without a problem.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "dash")
  require(dash)
  byte-code("\301\302!\210\301\303!\210\10\204\17\0\304 \210\305\306\307\310\311\303%\210\312\313\314\315\311\306\316\317&\7\210\312\320\321\322\316\323\311\306&\7\210\312\324\325\326\316..." [package--initialized require dash package package-initialize custom-declare-group auto-package-update nil "Automatically update Emacs packages." :group custom-declare-variable auto-package-update-interval 7 "Interval in DAYS for automatic package update." :type integer auto-package-update-before-hook 'nil "List of functions to be called before running an a..." hook auto-package-update-after-hook 'nil "List of functions to be called after running an au..." auto-package-update-last-update-day-filename ".last-package-update-day" "Name of the file in which the last update day is g..." string auto-package-update-buffer-name "*package update results*" "Name of the buffer that shows updated packages and..." auto-package-update-delete-old-versions "If not nil, delete old versions directories." boolean auto-package-update-prompt-before-update "Prompt user (y/n) before running auto-package-upda..." auto-package-update-hide-results "If not nil, the result of auto package update in b..."] 8)
  require(auto-package-update nil t)
  (not (require 'auto-package-update nil t))
  (if (not (require 'auto-package-update nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'auto-package-update) :error) (condition-case err (progn (setq auto-package-update-delete-old-versions t) (setq auto-package-update-hide-results t) t) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning1 :config err))))
  (condition-case err (if (not (require 'auto-package-update nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'auto-package-update) :error) (condition-case err (progn (setq auto-package-update-delete-old-versions t) (setq auto-package-update-hide-results t) t) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning1 :config err)))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning1 :catch err)))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/siery/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1050
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/siery/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/siery/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/siery/.emacs.d/init" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1594639ba149>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1594639ba0e1>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

[Here](https://gitgud.io/siery/dotemacs/-/tree/developement) are the last changes I think I made.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling `auto-package-update`?  The backtrace isn't quite what I'd expect from the corresponding `use-package` stanza: I don't see the `:ensure t` reflected anywhere, nor any `eval-after-load` corresponding to `:config`. But I haven't used `use-package` in years, so maybe things have changed since then...

Comment: When I tried to reinstall it get `byte-code: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, dash` message and the package was only deleted. No I get this message each time I try to install this package.

Comment: Are you able to reinstall any other packages that depend on `dash`, such as `magit`? If so, maybe there's a bug in `auto-package-update`.

Comment: No, and when I tried to reinstall dash it was removed as well. It just starts getting scary to use the reinstall.

Comment: Have you tried moving your existing `user-emacs-directory` out of the way as a backup, and installing everything from scratch?

Comment: Also, what is the value of `load-path` when `auto-package-update` is being loaded?

Comment: Don't just link to a repository and expect readers to go read your code there. Put all relevant code here, in the question. Q&A need to stand on their own.

Comment: @Basil: Well, it seems to work after reinstalling it from the clean environment. I don't know then what it been. Maybe I have malformed the compiled files somehow by some wild pointer.